# How to refresh picturebox with program.cs?

Tags: c#, winforms, nullreferenceexception

Program.cs code:

```
namespace _1
    {
     static class Program
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public static Form2 form2;
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        form2 = new Form2();

    }
}
```

Form1 Code:

```
Program.form2.pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

Error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Not sure why there's an error, I've asked google and no help.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error occured when you try to access without initializing/assigning any value.

Comment: What are trying to do exactly ?

Comment: Miller Koijam: I did assign the value
form2 = new Form2();

Comment: put form2 = new Form2() before the Application.Run(new Form1())

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Means that an object is `null`, or not assigned.

Hover over the variable while running or use a breakpoint, and check if `map` or `map.pictureBox1` are `null`

You need to make sure that you set your `map` to something before you use it, and from the given code I cannot give the specific reason for the error.

Comment: Since I set map to something in program.cs, it should have that error. map is null anyways so i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `Application.Run(new Form1());` before `form2 = new Form2();`

You need to put `form2 = new Form2();` *before* `Application.Run(new Form1());`.

I'm Assuming your refresh code is being called from that instance of Form1.

Comment: I did that and it still says"form2" is null.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `NullReferenceException` which generally occurs when you try to access an object having no reference. Generally speaking when the object is `null`.

In this case `form2` is `null`.

`Application.Run` is a blocking call. When you call this method it opens the form passed in parameter and stays blocked there until the form closes. So,

```
form2 = new Form2();
```

This line of code does not execute and you get a null form2. You can simply resolve the problem by simply reverting the lines like this,

```
form2 = new Form2();
Application.Run(new Form1());
```